# Cloud Functions for Firebase write operation inside a DB event function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm currently trying to learn Firebase functions.
This new feature seems to be pretty powerful and useful.

I'd like to use a function the catch a DB writing event, make a comparison with a specific location in DB and then write some data (depending on the comparison result) in another location in DB.

Here's my current Node.js code:

```
exports.verificaFineLavoro = functions.database.ref('/Aziende/{nomeazienda}/LogAsegno/{pushidbracciante}/{pushidlog}/Asegno')
.onWrite(event => {
  const original = event.data.val();
  console.log('VerificaFineLavoro', event.params.pushId, original);
  const aSegno = original;
  console.log('aSegno', aSegno +"");
  const FineLavoro = ref.parent.parent.parent.parent.child("Asegno/"+aSegno+"/FineLavoro");
  return event.data.ref.child('FL').set(FineLavoro);
});
```

Currently the function gets triggered but it stops working because of the references which are probably wrong.

Comment: If you already know that your references are wrong, what keeps you from fixing them?

Comment: I don't know how to make a reference inside a function and how to retrive data from it. The code i posted was an attemp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Cloud Functions for Firebase documentation on triggering from the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) contains code snippets that show how to access other nodes in the database.

For example, this snippet sets a value as a sibling to the node that triggered the function:

> ```
> return event.data.ref.parent.child('uppercase').set(uppercase);
> ```

Here's another snippet from the [sample on counting child nodes](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/child-count/functions/index.js#L23-L25):

> ```
> exports.countlikechange = 
> functions.database.ref('/posts/{postid}/likes/{likeid}').onWrite(event => {
>   const collectionRef = event.data.ref.parent;
>   const countRef = collectionRef.parent.child('likes_count');
>   ...
> ```

To access the root of the database use `event.data.ref.root` (to access the root node with the permissions of the user that triggered the function) or `event.data.adminRef.root` (to access the root with full administrative permission).

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try it now ;)

Comment: How can i build a reference from the root of my db?

Comment: event.data.ref.root or event.data.adminRef.root

Comment: @L.Gangemi You can also do admin.database().ref('path/to/ref') to reference some other path.

Comment: Can i use more .parent in sequence? I'd like to get the event reference and go back to a node at the start

Comment: I'd like to get {nomeazienda} value